# Cannot connect to jetty 9

Tags: jetty-9

Why can I not successfully connect to jetty?

I have the latest version of jetty 9.x running.  I have the jetty_base folder setup and when I drop war files into the folder I see them get expanded into the `/tmp` folder.

```
lsof -i :8080 
java    26488 jetty   85u  IPv6 400595      0t0  TCPlocalhost.localdomain:webcache (LISTEN)
```

> curl 'http://localhost:8080' curl: (7) Failed connect to
>   localhost:8080; Connection refused
>
> curl http://127.0.0.1:8080 curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:8080;
>   Connection refused

Comment: Can you telnet to 8080 port? `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`. You can also run `ps -eaf | grep jetty` to verify whether jetty is running

Comment: Looks like you are ipv6 not ipv4, try ipv6 loopback address as `::1`, for ipv4 it is `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the below output of `lsof -i:8080`

> java    26488 jetty   85u  **IPv6** 400595      0t0 
>   TCPlocalhost.localdomain:webcache (LISTEN)

It seems jetty is using ipv6 rather ipv4.

For ipv6, use `::1` as your loopback address. For ipv4, it is `127.0.0.1`.

**Changes you can make for localhost to work :**

If you wish to set localhost to work for both ipv6 and ipv4 you can make below changes to `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
# ... and below
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
```

As always, you can test the connectivity using `ping6 ::1` for an ipv6 ip and `ping 127.0.0.1` for ipv4.

Give a try!

Comment: Thanks to everyone that caught the ipv6 thing.  The VM was setup by someone else and it defaulted to IPv6.  It is amazing how your brain can filter out important details that are right in front of you.